# Operator Issue with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**So this is in my main.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const proModel = require('./doc/proModel');
const cabModel = require('./doc/cabModel');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/DocTest');

const pro1 = new proModel({
_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
Nom: "Ok",
Metier: {
    Pro: false,
    Secretaire: true

}
});

const cab1 = new cabModel({
InfoCab: {
    Nom: "WONKLAB"
}

});
const handleError = function (err) {
console.error(err);

};

pro1.save(function (err) {
if (err) return handleError(err);
});
if (pro1.Metier.Pro != false) {
cab1.Pro._idPro = pro1._id;
} else if (pro1.Metier.Secretaire != false){
cab1.Pro._idSecretaire = pro1._id
}


cab1.save(function (err) {
if (err) return handleError(err);
});
```

**I have the weirdest output in the shell if I have this :**

```
if (pro1.Metier.Pro = true) { // turning != false into =true
cab1.Pro._idPro = pro1._id;
} else if (pro1.Metier.Secretaire = true){ // same here
cab
```

**Doing so gives me this output**

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.pros.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59c587e4d76f5325dbf3c241"),
"Nom" : "Ok",
"Metier" : {
    "Pro" : true, // Stated as false previously
    "Secretaire" : true
},
"__v" : 0
```

**When Pro is stated as false and secretary as true.
Can anyone explain the mechanism behind this. I got the fix but I'd like to understand the logic here.**

**Cheers,**

Comment: if (pro1.Metier.Pro = true) is an assignment and always evaluates to true

Comment: Ok, there is still a problem, if I do this :
Pro: false,Secretaire: true,Proprietaire: true,Remplacant: true.
It will only show Pro: false, Secretaire : true in the shell. How can I get past the 1st true so it applies true to the rest as I state?

Comment: at first, try to replace `if (xyz = true)` with `if (xyz)`, and update your question (e.g. do not add relevant info into a comment)